# Restore CouchDB database from /var/lib/couchdb Backup

Tags: couchdb, backup, restore

I accidentally deleted a database file but I have a backup of the . couch file in /var/lib/couchdb (as described here: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_make_filesystem_backups)

Unfortunately, placing the my_database.couch file from the backup into the  /var/lib/couchdb folder does not solve the problem. In Futon, when I try to open the database, I get a popup saying "Error: unknown error, function_clause"

How does it work?
Is there a repair or integration tool for .couch files from a backup?
I'm on Windows7, 64bit

Comment: You restarted your CouchDB service/process? It should just work.